# Angularjs - Perform a function on text input as it is being typed

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a Roman numeral calculator that converts numbers, typed in a text input, to the numerals instantly. I understand how to bind a variable to the text input but I don't know how to 'perform a function' on it as it's being typed. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ng-change directive : [here the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Example

In template

```
<input type="text" ng-change="yourFunction(value)" ng-model="value"/>
```

In controller

```
$scope.value = ""

$scope.yourFunction = function(value){
   //Put code logic here
}
```

EDIT :

In your case, you can also create a filter

```
module.filter("convertToRomanNumber", function(){
    //Improve code logic here
    return function(input){
        var value=""; 
        for(var i=0; i<input; i++){
            value+="I"
        } 
        return value;
    }
})
```

and call it in your template

```
 <input type="text" ng-change="yourFunction(value)" ng-model="value"/>
 {{value | convertToRomanNumber}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain your usage of 'value' throughout the template and controller? I'm confused

Comment: In controller version,  $scope.value is the model behind yout input field. In ng-change, i call a function and pass this model in parameters, so i can use it directly (not by using the scope) in my function

Comment: Thanks Varkal! Really helped me

Answer (score 4):

$scope.watch on the ng-model of the text input. Then run the code you want to execute on the ng-model variable.

e.g.

```
// html...
<input type=text ng-model="textBox" />

// controller
$scope.$watch('$scope.textBox', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   // do stuff to the text everytime it changes
});
```

The benefit of this $scope.$watch is for example you don't want to execute the function on the newValue unless it is 2 or 3 characters more. It just gives you some more control over the function compared to a simple ng-change.